# Collection to 2d list in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am trying to pass a MongoDB collection to a python 2d list. I need for each sublist to contain only the values of each key within the document. For example, if the MongoDB documents are:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98392"),
   name: 'marie',
   age: '23',
   gender: 'female'
}
```

and

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98391"),
   name: 'john',
   age: '43',
   gender: 'male'
}
```

I need to get something like:

```
[
  [ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98392"), 'marie', '23', 'female],
  [ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98391"), 'john', '43', 'male']
]
```

I am new to MongoDB and PyMongo. For now, the closest I have been able to do is something like this:

```
people = mongo.db.population
people_key_list = ['_id', 'name', 'age', 'gender'] 
people_list = []

for item in people.find():
    people_list.append(item)
```

But the structure of the results are not really what I need:

```
[
  ['ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98392")','ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98391")'],
  ['marie','john'],['23','43'],['female','male']
]
```

I could rotate the 2d list, but I am sure there should be a way to generate the structure I need efficiently from the start... but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have `people_key_list` defined with the names of the keys, so just do a [`map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) over that list and extract the values:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId

data = [
  {
    '_id': ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98392"),
    'name': 'marie',
    'age': '23',
    'gender': 'female'
  },
  {
    '_id': ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98391"),
    'name': 'john',
    'age': '43',
    'gender': 'male'
  }
]

client = MongoClient();
db = client['test']

db.population.remove({})
db.population.insert_many(data)


people_key_list = ['_id', 'name', 'age', 'gender']
people_list = []

for person in db.population.find():
  people_list.append(map(lambda k: person[k],people_key_list))

print(people_list)
```

Or even just nest the [`map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) for that matter:

```
people_list = map(lambda person:
  map(lambda k: person[k],people_key_list),
  db.population.find()
)
```

Either would return:

```
[
  [ObjectId('5099803df3f4948bd2f98392'), u'marie', u'23', u'female'], 
  [ObjectId('5099803df3f4948bd2f98391'), u'john', u'43', u'male']
]
```

Comment: I don't know why I keep getting "builtins.KeyError KeyError: 'name'" any idea?